# React component is inheriting parent components div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to understand why this is happening:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-9emtzg?file=pages/index.js

1. See the "you are not logged in" message
2. Click the login button to see the welcome message in a grey box (`#container`)
3. Reload the preview screen (click the refresh icon next to the URL bar)
4. See the welcome message but it is now in a red box (`#error`)

Step 4 should show the welcome message inside `#container` just like the state change.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Using Next.js but I don't think thats the issue.

Comment: so the ID of you container is replaced by error when you reload, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Essentially yes... its like Next/React is swapping the surrounding `<Container>` for `<Error>` on page refresh

Comment: ah yes that makes more sense then swapping the ID.. Maybe it is a render missmatch - the inital UI not rendering what was rendered by the server. I think that if you just do it with react with localStorage instead of cookies then it will work just fine. So in short, seems like a next js issue. I will try to do some research

Comment: On another note, you'd get more info if you switch to the 18.2.0 version of react if that is at all supported with next js at this point.

Comment: are you using ReactDOM.hydrate() or ReactDOM.render()?

Comment: That was a good shout switching to React 18... I figured out the error "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Comment: After looking around the console I found this as well: `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <span> in <div>.`.
This is at span < UserAccount < div < Container < Home < MyApp.
Someone on GIT outlines how to resolve this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35773.

These errors are easy to miss because they are only logged as warnings in the console and wont crash your app but will cause chaos. Luckily react 18+ decied to start showing popups.

Comment: Think I resolved this with your React 18 hint, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this by setting the state with useEffect...

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (hasCookie('logged_in')) {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  }
}, []);
```